# AngularJS export SVG to PDF

Tags: javascript, pdf, svg, pdfmake

I'm trying to export a `<svg>` element sitting in DOM to a PDF file, generated on client side.
I tried with different libraries, and pdfmake is so close to what I want. Any working example with this library or any other library would be helpful.

```
    downloadPdf = function() {
        //var docDefinition = { content: 'This is an sample PDF'};
        var html = d3.select("svg")
          .attr("version", 1.1)
          .attr("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")
          .node().parentNode.innerHTML;
        console.log(btoa(html));
        var imgsrc = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,'+btoa(html);
        var docDefinition = {content: [{image: imgsrc}]}
        pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).open('Sample.pdf');    
   }
```

Answer (score 4):

pdfMake does not support vector graphics. In this case you need to take the bypass through canvas with [fabricJS](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/) or [canvg](https://github.com/gabelerner/canvg), once you've imagery you can place it in pdfMake

```
// Create fabric instance
var canvas = new fabric.StaticCanvas( undefined, {
    width: 500,
    height: 500,
} );

// Load SVG document; add to canvas;
fabric.parseSVGDocument(<svg element>,function(objects, options) {
    var g = fabric.util.groupSVGElements( objects, options );
    var data = "";

    // ADD ELEMENTS
    canvas.add( g );

    // EXPORT TO DATA URL
    data = canvas.toDataURL({
        format: "jpeg"
    });

    console.log(data);

// REVIVER
},function(svg,group) {
    // possiblitiy to filter the svg elements or adapt the fabric object
});
```

Comment: I wish I could upvote more than once. Thank you very much for pointing me to this solution.
Actually I tried both of the plugins. With canvg, one of the labels in highchart piechart was overlapping a value.
Tried fabricJS, it was better.

Finally I used a simpler solution from this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/willkoehler/1p81fbzs/
It is possible to have some pitfalls, but works for my case just fine.